# Steam games disappearing after reboot

Tags: games, steam

I'm installing games, and as default it is being saved in user/home. The thing is, I don't have enough space for all of them to be there. Therefore I bought another HDD to use. However, when trying to install the games on the new destination, something weird happens. It works perfectly fine until I reboot my computer, and then will have to download again.

Ok so a tiny update, I've been looking around the installing destination at the
settings. I found a way to change this by opening the settings > Downloads > Steam Library Folders > Add Folder > home > user > .media > HDD. Went back to the download settings and chose the new folder as default. This solved it.

Comment: May be a problem with steam itself.  Try contacting them.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Post an answer if you have found a solution

Comment: I have ^^ Second paragraph